# To which value set ulimit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, debian, optimization

I'm setting up nginx from what I've understood the `worker_connections` value must not exceed the maximum number of open file descriptors retruned by `ulimit -n`.

On my fresh 16.04 ubuntu installation `ulimit -n` return `1024` which is very low comparing to what `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` -> `3269456`.

1) Does those two values are related ?

2) If yes by which factor should I divide the value returned `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` to have a safe `ulimit` and `worker_connections` value ?